# Regex to pick up potentially multiple XML tags inside a tag of a given type

Tags: regex, regex-group

I need to convert a text of the form

```
<BTEXT>
<PARA ID="00001">legit text<PTEXT><PDAT>more legit text<BOLD></PDAT>finally</PARA>
</BTEXT>
...
<BTEXT>
<PARA ID="00002">legit text<PTEXT></PDAT>more legit text<BOLD><PDAT>finally</PARA>
</BTEXT>
```

to

```
<BTEXT>
<PARA ID="00001">legit text more legit text finally</PARA>
</BTEXT>
...
<BTEXT>
<PARA ID="00002">legit text more legit text finally</PARA>
</BTEXT>
```

That is, remove all tags inside `<PARA>` tags.

I can certainly match these inside tags individually with like `<[^<>]*?>`, but I'm failing to scope this to only between the `<PARA>` tags. Once I put `<PARA>` at the beginning, one needs non-capturing groups, and with them I only grab two instances and that's it.

Any advice would be appreciated. Live example [here](https://regex101.com/r/pr0DKY/1)

Comment: This may look like XML, but given the unclosed `<BOLD>` tag, it is not XML (or at least, not well-formed XML). If it is XML, you should use an XML parser, not regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

This captures `legit text` as group 1:

```
<PARA.*?>([^<]*)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/Q5lgpcF1DVtbAl).

Comment: Thank you, but not quite. I also need `more legit text`, `finally` and any other possible instances of anything that is not inside a `<`, `>` pair but is inside the `<PARA>` tags.

Comment: Then you should have said that in your question, which states *I need to keep only "legit text"*. Please edit your question accordingly.